# JavaScript - access iframe in iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, window, document

To access a iframe in my main document i use the following code

```
// First iFrame in the main document
var iFrame = document.querySelector("iframe");

// Second iFrame in the iFrame
var iFrame_2 = iFrame.contentWindow.document.querySelector("iframe");

// Third iFrame ... here i get a "permission denied error"
var iFrame_3 = iFrame_2.contentWindow.document.querySelector("iframe");
```

When i try to access the third iFrame i get permission denie to access document, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the second iframe linked to an external website?
Their server might block CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing), which is why your third iframe gets a permission denied.

Comment: Yes, the iframe is a external website, there is no way to change elements in a external iframe?

Comment: There is no way to change elements in an external iframe, at least not when the servers blocks CORS requests.

Comment: But why an iframe request can access it and a XMLHTTPREQUEST can't access the url?

Comment: Because an iframe embeds the page, while an XHR requests the page. The server could interpret this different, based on the security settings.